# How to extract value from dynamic generation

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am trying to use value from dynamic generation.

My payload looks like:

```
{

"payload": [

    {

        "questionDefinitionId": "jRs6zAh3GGt3G8tL9SzUrS8SiXyg6EirSElv3VRpX_Q=",

        "questionText": "What was your childhood nickname?",

        "languageCode": "en",

        "questionNumber": 1,

        "disabled": false

    },

    {

        "questionDefinitionId": "pmyZ4excucJBuFvSPCr6yIvO74vZS8DUNPx0GYVR57E=",

        "questionText": "What is your favorite team?",

        "languageCode": "en",

        "questionNumber": 2,

        "disabled": false

    },

    {

        "questionDefinitionId": "awE_x8cXHcc0uhJ7lgtjzX1NtgA0IQBBWu7iDbVqW-k=",

        "questionText": "What is the name of your favorite childhood friend?",

        "languageCode": "en",

        "questionNumber": 1,

        "disabled": false

    },

    {
```

This generation is different every time when is executed.

I need to get: jRs6zAh3GGt3G8tL9SzUrS8SiXyg6EirSElv3VRpX_Q=, which is questionDefinitionId value for the questionNumber: 1, but is always generated in the different location in the Json file

but every time their order is in different place in the long list.

Comment: Why do you need this value? what are you searching exactly?

Comment: i am searching for: jRs6zAh3GGt3G8tL9SzUrS8SiXyg6EirSElv3VRpX_Q=, but every time it is different value. I need for later usage

Comment: How do you know this is the right value? it's always this exact value?

Comment: it's always the exact count, but different value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your payload appears a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) object to me, in this case it makes much more sense to go for [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor), this will be way easier to implement/read/support/etc.

For example you can get `questionDefinitionId` attribute value where `questionText` is `What was your childhood nickname?` using `==` [Filter Operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators) like:

```
$.payload[?(@.questionText == 'What was your childhood nickname?')].questionDefinitionId
```

Demo:

[image]

If you want the `questionDefinitionId` where `questionNumber` is `1` amend the JSON Path Expression to look like:

```
$.payload[?(@.questionNumber == '1')].questionDefinitionId
```

However in your example there are 2 questions with number 1

See [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) for more information on the concept.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
 (?<="questionDefinitionId": ")(.+?)(?=")
```

Comment: i updated my description. this is returning all the questionDefinitionId values. I need the one associated with questionNumber": 1